# GLSL - When and where is the vertex and fragment called?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I want to know when exactly the vertex and fragment shader is called exactly in the opengl loop. Is it at the end of your glutDisplayFunc() or glutMainLoop(), or is it at every vertex draw call? And do the vertex and fragment get consecutively called one after the other(ie: vertex then fragment), or a completely different times?

Say i have the following snippet of code:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(rot,0.0f,1.0f,0.0);
    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,25);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    drawSphere(4,20,20); // draw triangles

    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,5);
    drawSphere(4,20,20); // draw triangles
glPopMatrix();
```

Does the vertex shader get called after each vertex call, then reads the current matrix on top of stack, then send that pre-defined ModelView matrix uniform to the vertex shader? When is the fragment shader run?

Comment: The short answer is that it doesn't matter for the operation of your program how your particular OpenGL implementation handles this.

Comment: Well one thing to point out is that your code is using fixed function pipeline, so the programmable units might not get run at all if your drawcall is `glEnd`.

Comment: What are the fixed-function pipeline calls im using so i can change them? Also their is a glUseProgram() call just above this code snippet

Comment: Actually... all of them. `Rotate/Translate/PushMatrix/PopMatrix` operate on global matrix stack, and `Color` changes the global vertex color value, which were both superseeded by uniform variables (or vertex attributes).

Comment: Oh, are you talking about putting vertex/color information on a VAO/VBO? If so, would that make pushing and popping matrices redundant?

Comment: You should investigate the general graphics pipeline. I think you are actually asking two different questions here. One is whether a draw command immediately starts drawing something and the other is the general sequence of operations that leads to fragment generation (*e.g.* vertex processing, primitive assembly, clipping, rasterization, frgment processing, blending, ...) That entire process is outlined at a high-level [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview). Fundamentally vtx and frag shaders do not run simultaneously on the same primitive, they are pipeline stages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it at the end of your glutDisplayFunc() or glutMainLoop(),

Neither, because GLUT **is not** part of OpenGL. It's just some library (for creating simple OpenGL applications).

> or is it at every vertex draw call?

From the programmers point of view it's not specified when it happens exactly. OpenGL has a command queue and things are asserted to be processed between them entering the command queue and reaching a so called "synchronization point". A synchronization point is any command that makes use or transfers data outside of the OpenGL context (like an image read with `glReadPixels`) produced by former OpenGL commands.

For all practical means you can assume that vertices and fragments get processed, as soon as a whole primitive has been specified. So if you draw triangles, then every 3 vertices you got all you need to draw a triangle and processing it commences.

Comment: Too bad, I thought I might answer a question once in a while and it gets stolen :). I'd add a bit about `glFlush`, because that also should force the rendering operation. Other than that, it's always about "when will you need the pixels", and with modern drivers... yeah, you never know.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: `glFlush` does not force the rendering to complete by the time it returns. That would be `glFinish`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Nobody said anything about when it finishes. `glFlush (...)` forces GL to start working on the command queue in "finite time." It basically tells GL to get its butt busy doing some of the commands in the queue rather than just adding more commands to it and waiting until a time it feels appropriate to start working on the queue ;)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: The way I read Bartek's comment, he was suggesting to list `glFlush` as a synchronization point. Which it is not. I'm quite familiar with what `glFlush` does.